# How to link the user.permissions in Django to another table?

Tags: django

I want to link the permissions(read/write/hide) given to a certain table of a row , to be linked with the user.permissions that Django provides . Is it possible ?

The permissions here are based on a table generated from a spatial data . These permissions are then given to a particular user .

How to map those permissions , if a permission table exists . ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want object based permissions? [django-gaurdian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian) is one option if this is the case.